# GREP get all strings that contain a given string

Tags: regex, perl, grep, dynamically-generated

I have the following script:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my @test = ("a", "b", "c", "a", "ca");
 my @res = grep(m#a#, @test);

 print (join(", ", @res)."\n");
```

It supposed to return only strings that contain `a`. It works perfectly.

The problem is that I need to be able to get these string dynamically.
I tried the following:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my $match = "a";
 my @test = ("a", "b", "c", "a", "ca");
 my @res = grep($match, @test);

 print (join(", ", @res)."\n");
```

The result is:

> a, b, c, a, ca

What should I do to be able to `grep` the array with a dynamical variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`grep` takes each element in the LIST you provide as the second parameter and checks whether the first parameter is true or false. In your case, `$match` will always be true, because it will always be "a". Try this:

```
my @res = grep( m/$match/, @test);
```

If your dynamic string can contain more than just alpha-numeric characters, you should also quote it:

```
my @res = grep( m/\Q$match/, @test);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want:

```
my @res = grep { $_ =~ $match } @test;
```